# Bounds on inter-word spacing

Tags: spacing, layout, glue

Is there any way to put both lower and upper bounds on inter-word spacing for a certain region of text within a document? That is, allow LaTeX to adjust within a certain range, say 0.2em to 0.5em. Also, what's the default for this?

Comment: each font already specifies an optimum amount and an allowable amount to shrink and an allowable amount to stretch.  as always in tex these aren't hard bounds though but the penalty for exceeding them incrreases rapidly leading to underful box  warnings if the space is over stretched.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In certain cases, however, I want to decrease the maximum, at the very least. (It really doesn't *look* optimum within the context.) Can I do that?

Comment: you can override the font-specified amounts by setting `\spaceskip` (normal space) and `\xspaceskip` (end of sentence space) to whatever you like eg `\setlength\spaceskip{5pt minus 1pt plus 1pt}` will mean tex will try really hard to keep between 4 and 6pt space.  I'm sure we hav ean answer about that on site already.

Comment: but if inter-word spacing is being over-stretched it's usually better to use raggedright and niot stretch interword space at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. Feel free to either close this as a duplicate then, or if not, write an answer and I'll accept it. Small somewhat-related question: what does ~expand to? I couldn't find out, but presume it's `\nobreak\space`.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this: be careful that you specify e.g. `plus 1pt` before `minus 1pt`, or you will get lots of strange errors! i.e., `\setlength\spaceskip{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}`.

Comment: @Noldorin `~` expands to `\nobreakspace{}`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks. Is that different? And what are the braces after for?

Comment: @Noldorin Yes, but the details are really more a different question then a comment.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Fair enough, thanks. If you feel like it, feel free to write me in the chat. I'd appreciate it.